# excel vba- writing over errors returned from formula in a loop (type mismatch)

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

in column H of a my worksheet is a vlookup formula, some of the rows in column H returns an "#n/a" error. I cannot seem to get VBA to check for errors in Column H and replace it with a string. here is what I have so far:

```
For Each F In activeworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("H11:H90" )
If F = "#N/A" Then
F.Offset(0, 1) = "failed"
Else
F.Offset(0, 1) = "found"
End If
Next
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
If F = "#N/A" Then
```

with

```
If CVErr(F.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
```

I am guessing that you are trying to find the cells with #NA error? I hope you know that you do not need VBA for this? You can use `=ISNA()` formula in `Col I` to get what you want?

Comment: for some reason it's treating all the Fs as errors (even where the value is not a a vlookup error). Where there's a blank cell, then it treated it as a non-error. I tried pasting the range as values and it returns "type mismatch"

Comment: I am sure you are doing something wrong. Can I see the sample workbook? If yes then please post it on a free file sharing site and share the link here:)

Comment: i created a fake data set and tried your code and it worked... so it must be something wrong with my original data set... unfortunately i cannot post it. I'll need to figure out what that is.. thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: `If F.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)` or change your lookup formula: `=IFERROR(<your lookup here>, "No match!")`

Comment: @TimWilliams `CVErr(F.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA)` and `F.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)` both are correct :)

Comment: @machump: I had tested the code before posting :) I am sure there is something which you are missing in the original dataset. You can see it works with the sample data that you created.\

Comment: A small note: `CVErr(F.Value)` will give you `Error 2042` if it has a `#NA` error and `Error 0` where there is no error. `CVErr(xlErrNA)` also gives you `Error 2042`.

Comment: I thought it should / could be `If F.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then` when I first saw your answer, but that gives a type mismatch if `F.Value` is not an error.  (And, if `F.Value` contains `5`, `CVErr(F.Value)` gives an `Error 5` as the result, not an `Error 0`.  So if `F.Value` was a #N/A error **or the number 2042** it will return an `Error 2042`.)

Comment: @SiddharthRout -  running `CVErr()` on a cell with a non-error value gave me a runtime error, but on retesting that's only the case for a *non-numeric* value...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are testing for **any** error condition, and not just the specific `#N/A` error, you could use the `IsError` function:

```
For Each F In activeworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("H11:H90" )
    If IsError(F.Value) Then
        F.Offset(0, 1) = "failed"
    Else
        F.Offset(0, 1) = "found"
    End If
Next
```

If you are after the specific `#N/A` error then it is best to still use `IsError` first, and then test for the specific error:

```
For Each F In activeworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("H11:H90" )
    If IsError(F.Value) Then
        If F.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
            F.Offset(0, 1) = "failed"
        Else
            F.Offset(0, 1) = "failed for some unknown reason"
        End If
    Else
        F.Offset(0, 1) = "found"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: can you think of any situations where this formulas pretty much see everything as an error (except blanks) even where they are not errors? For example, the vlookup formula refers to a table array in a different workbook

Comment: @machump - No I can't think of any scenarios at all where, if the value in the cell is valid, VBA will think it is invalid.  Try testing your data by putting in a formula in a cell in Excel somewhere which is something like `=H11*1` and make sure that returns a valid number (or use `=H11&"X"` if your data isn't numeric)