# Checking for #NV (german for #N/A) but it doesn't find it

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am running into a problem while checking for the value `#NV` (german version of `#N/A`) in my VBA Script. I am checking all active cells in column D, however even if there is a cell with the value `#NV` it does not trigger the msgBox. Always receiving a

> runtime error '13' type mismatch.

```
    Dim checkRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim missingFound As Boolean

    Set checkRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row)
    missingFound = False

    For Each cell In checkRange
        If cell.Value = "#NV" Then
            missingFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    If missingFound Then
        MsgBox "Missing Value"   
    End If
```

I tried setting it to `isEmpty` by running a replace-function in the same script beforehand, but it also did not find the value "#NV". I also tried `IsNA`, getting a runtime error '438'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try checking for #NA - I have this idea that vba expects the English version...

Comment: doesn't work, still getting the runtime error '13', sorry I forgot to mention this the first time...

Comment: Just from the top of my head: if, in German, "#NA" is replaced by "#NV", wouldn't this mean that the formula or function `IsNA()` is replaced by `IsNV()` too?

Comment: I actually did not think of this, however according to the microsoft documentation it shows "IsNA" however, on the sidebar it actually says "IstNV". Simply look at [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.isna). However I may come back if I need to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it myself!

For anyone interested, checking with 'IsError' is the way to go!

```
For Each cell In checkRange
    If IsError(cell.Value) Then
        missingFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248985/excel-vba-writing-over-errors-returned-from-formula-in-a-loop-type-mismatch)

Comment: actually no, but thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Note that `IsError` gets `True` for **any** error in the cell not only NA/NV errors. If you compare the cell value to `CVErr(xlErrNA)` you get only `True` for NA/NV errors but not for the others.

Comment: Thanks for this information! In this case any error is actually okay. However I will keep in mind when working on future scripts!